# I am trying to copy file from remote sever to local machine

Tags: linux, scp

I get this error:

> ssh: connect to host ' my ip addr ' port 22: Connection refused

I am trying to copy a CSV file, from REMOTE SERVER to my computer, using SCP command.

This is my code:

```
scp remote_server_username@remote_server_ip_addr:'path/to/file/i_want to copy' my_local_computer_username@ip_addr:'path_to file/where/i_want_to_save'
```

Comment: This is not code and the problem is not related to coding and thus is off-topic for Stackoverflow. Perhaps try over at [Superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: And, creating a new account because your previous question was closed, is not the way to go here on SO 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59691788/i-get-this-error-ssh-connect-to-host-my-ip-addr-port-22-connection-refused